# What is "self" doing

Tags: python

Here in this code they are checking the equality of `self` with self.parent.leftChild    . why they are doing this

```
def isLeftChild(self):
    return self.parent and self.parent.leftChild == self
```

The site is:-`class TreeNode`: http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/Trees/SearchTreeImplementation.html

Comment: 1. `self` is not an operator. 2. What do you mean *"how"*? 3. It's not clear which value you're referring to as which. Is it the formulation `foo and foo.bar == foo` that you find surprising? It's not actually checking equality with two parameters, it's checking first that `self.parent` is truthy (probably `not None`) and secondly that its `leftChild` attribute is equal to `self`.

Comment: here they are doing self.parent and self.parent.leftChild == self i want to know what do they meant by doing this

Comment: `(self.parent is not None) and (self.parent.leftChild == self)` is probably a less confusing formulation, does that make more sense?

Comment: `self` is not an operator, it is a reference to the object for which a method is called. If `node.leftChild()` is invoked, `self == node` _inside_ the `leftChild` code. In other languages, like Java or C++ or JavaScript, the same thing is called `this`. [Read more](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html).

Comment: what is there in self i mean i have seen the things like a=1 and then we can do return a==1

Comment: See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/2709821/3001761 for more explanation of `self`. As a starting point, note that it's *just a parameter of the method*.

Comment: sir can you tell me what is the value that is in the self argument with which they are comparing self.parent.leftChild

Comment: `self` is the instance of the class the method belongs to. If you're not familiar with classes you should read the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Here in this code they are checking the equality of self with the other two parameters.

What? Where? No. `a and b == c` doesn't relate `a` and `c` together in any way.

```
self.parent and self.parent.leftChild == self
```

checks if

1. `self.parent` has a meaningful value (is not `None`) and, if so,
2. `self.parent.leftChild` equals to the given `self`.

In other words, it does what its name says: it checks if "we" are identical to our parent's left child. This, of course, only works if we have a parent. If we haven't, we aren't its left child.

Note: What I just said about "is not `None`" is only half the truth. To be exact, it checks if there is a "truthy value", i. e. a value which evaluates true in the context of conditional expressions. As one normally uses `None` in the case of an absent node such as `parent`, what I wrote is clear enough.

Comment: sir can you please explain the second point

Comment: "Sir" sounds a bit ironical onplatforms like these.
Anyway, imagine you are an object in a tree, in a kind of parent/child relationship. In this structure, every child knows its parent, and every parent knows its (left and right) childs.
So here we ask about our parent (`self.parent`) and ask this parent about its left child (`self.parent.leftChild`). If this one is identical to ourselves, we found out that we are the left child of our parent.

Comment: Yes I started Getting you , but again they are doing (==self)what is stored in (self) and also in the link that i have mentioned they in the same class they are in the replaceNodedata method they are even putting the value of self    (self.leftChild.parent = self) it confuses me

Comment: Might be slightly more accurate to say that `self.parent` checks if it has a truthy value instead of `not None`

Comment: @VarunRathi I am not sure what exactly confuses you. Is it just the lack of the basics? An explanation what is `self` can be found directly on the right of the question, there are links to other questions about the same topic ("Linked", "Related"). Besides, there is a very fine tutorial at the python doc site. (You were pointed to that by other commenters directly below your question.) Essentially, `self` holds a reference to the object just worked on, the object whose method just has been called. And `xy == self` compares if the variable `xy` refers to the same object as `self`.